# ARMv7: When throwing exception within library: "terminate called without an active exception"

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I am cross compiling with gcc 4.9.2 for armv7hv (gcc-4.9.2_armv7hf_glibc-2.9).
Theres a main executable and a library with one exported function `Foo()`.

What I experience is that if I throw an exception within that library's function `Foo()`, and try to catch it right away it's caught.

**However** if within that function I create an object on the stack that throws a std::exception, it is not caught and I get the following output and the program terminates right away:

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

These are my compiler calls:

```
arm-drm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -fPIC -pipe -ggdb -o MyLib.o -c MyLib.cpp
arm-drm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -fPIC -pipe -ggdb -o LibraryLoader.o -c LibraryLoader.cpp
arm-drm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -g3 -ggdb -Wall -fPIC -pipe -isystem /sysroot/usr/local/include\ -fsigned-char -D_USE_EMBEDDED_ -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -static-libstdc++ -lpthread -ldl -shared -L/sysroot/usr/local/lib MyLib.o LibraryLoader.o -o myLib.so

arm-drm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -fPIC -pipe -ggdb -o Main.o -c Main.cpp
arm-drm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -g3 -ggdb -Wall -fPIC -pipe -isystem /sysroot/usr/local/include\ -fsigned-char -D_USE_EMBEDDED_ -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -static-libstdc++ -lpthread -ldl -L/sysroot/usr/local/lib  Main.o -o Main.linux-arm
```

This my code:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string sLibname("myLib.so");
    std::string sInitFuncName = "Foo";

    void *handle = NULL;
    long (*func_Initialize)(void*);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen(sLibname.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);

    if (!handle) {
        fputs(dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    *(void**)(&func_Initialize) = dlsym(handle, sInitFuncName.c_str());

    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Call library function 'Foo'\n");
    func_Initialize(NULL);
    printf("Call library function 'Foo' DONE\n");

    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

**MyLib.hpp**

```
extern "C" {
long DEBMIInitialize();
}
```

**MyLib.cpp**

```
#include "LibraryLoader.hpp"
#include "MyLib.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <exception>

long Foo()
{

    try {
        std::exception e;
        throw e;
    }
    catch (std::exception)
    {
        //This is caught
        printf("Caught std::exception\n");
    }



    try {
        LibraryLoader oLibLoader;
        oLibLoader.Run();
    }
    catch (std::exception)
    {
        //This is not caught
        printf("Caught std::exception from ClLibrayLoader\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**LibraryLoader.hpp**

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdio.h>

class LibraryLoader
{
public:
    LibraryLoader() {};
    ~LibraryLoader() {};
    void Run() {
        std::exception e;
        throw e;
    };
};
```

EDIT: I just noticed that the (2nd) exception is also caught when I add the compiler flag for optimization `-O1` (`O2`, `O3`..).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create the Exception with new(), as it is local in "MyLib.cpp::Foo()".